# I can't able to find Trash directory in my Ubuntu 20.04 Server? Is that not existing by default?

Tags: 20.04, trash

I have installed fresh Ubuntu Server image version 20.04 in the nested azure VM. I have copied certain files in /var/.../files/ directory and deleted those files using rm * command.

After copied the files the Virtual Hard Disk size has grown to 148GB from 23GB size. After deletion I expected to shrink back to 23GB. But it still stays in the same size. I am perplexed. The /var/lib/docker/overlay2... directories have listed with huge sizes.

I was looking for Trash folder in */home//.local*. But this directory is not existing for me. What's wrong here?

Comment: Trash is a *desktop* paradigm; so it's likely you have logs that are filling the space.  You've not indicated what *file-system* you're using (which too can influence whether or not trash is possible), but I doubt your space issue relates to *trash*.

Comment: @guiverc I am not sure about this. But when I used df command it shows two file system types primarily. Overlay and tmpfs.

Comment: I generally use `du` (*disk usage*) to track down what's using space... but on a server it's not normally trash (that requires an extra service to operate & manager it; servers usually have knowledgeable users who (a) don't need it and (b) don't want to waste resources for it to run)